# Can I change my migrations depending on the database adapter? How will it reflects in the schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

Specifically, I want to add an `spatial` index in a `multi_polygon` column. This works nicely in **PostgreSQL** but not in **MySQL**, so I was thinking of somthing like:

```
create_table :figures do |t|
  t.multi_polygon :polygon
end

add_index :figures, :polygon if database_adapter == :postgresql
```

Is it possible and a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass index this way

add_index(:figures, [:polygon,:extra1,:extra2], :name => 'fig_poly')

This will work on mysql,postgresql,oracle and db2.

Comment: What are :extra1 and :extra2? Another columns?